# Change element IDs and classses with preprocessing

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, gulp

I'm a big believer in using human readable names for things, but I similarly realise that `.easy-to-read-and-informative-name-for-element` is a bit over the top for production code.

So is there a way to maintain long and informative names for development and turn it into the shortest name possible, like `.a`, in production code? In all places where you might reference it, markup, css, js?

I'm open to using Grunt, Gulp, Webpack - or whatever else that might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **css-loader** from Webpack to obfuscate classes: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader using the `module` options.

Comment: I don't see how that can achieve what I'm describing. Can you provide an example of how you think it does?

Comment: This module of webpack takes your class names and transforms it to a randomly generated name (according to the options you passed). See this for example: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reducing-css-bundle-size-70-by-cutting-the-class-names-and-using-scope-isolation-625440de600b

Comment: How do you align the randomised CSS names with markup and javascript references to the same element?

Comment: This will align the CSS classes that are present in your HTML markup. For JavaScript, depends if you're using a library or just plain JavaScript. With React for example, you could avoid it adding the handlers directly to the components. With vanilla or jQuery, instead using CSS classes to add handlers, you could have a `data` attribute and query it with that: `$("[data-name]")`